# jenkins archive artifact excluding all subdirectory

Tags: jenkins, archive, artifact, fileset

I have a couple of job in Jenkins that archive artifact from the source tree for another job (some unit tests or alike). I have the current situation :

```
top_dir
  \scripts_dir
      \some_files
      \dir1
      \dir2
      \dir3
  \other_dir
```

I would like to archive all that is in "top_dir" including the *files* in "scripts_dir", but not the subdirectories "dir1, dir2,...", which I do not know the name, that are in "scripts_dir". These subdirs are actually Windows directory joints that point to other places on the disk, and I do not want them to be copied.

How do I achieve this with the inculde/excludes pattern of Jenkins ?

I already tried, having include=top_dir/ , exclude=

```
**/scripts_dir/*/
**/scripts_dir/*/**
**/scripts_dir/**/*
```

but it always exculdes the whole "scripts_dir" folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, by using brute force, I found that the following expression does exclude all the files in the subdirectories of `scripts_dir` (whatever symlink or not), then removing these subdirs, while keeping the files directly in `scripts_dir` :

```
**/scripts_dir/**/*/*/
```

Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [ANT manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html), there an `followsymlinks` attribute that defaults to true. You said those things you want to exclude are symlinks (although i am not sure if this will work with Windows joints). Try adding `followsymlinks=false`

Another solution: if all your files under `scripts_dir` have a set number of characters in the extension, you can put that into your include statement. This will only pickup files with extensions of 3 characters:
`**/scripts_dir/*.???`
More on this [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns)

Comment: Unfortunately, I use only the web interface of Jenkins. So, hacking into the config.xml is not an option. Alternatively, the files in `scripts_dir` have different extension size...

Comment: But they all have an extension? So you can include multiple matches for `**/scripts_dir/*.?, **/scripts_dir/*.??, **/scripts_dir/*.???, **/scripts_dir/*.????`. This will handle upto 4 character extension